# CQLSH returns "Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH"

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra

[root@qlg73 bin]# cqlsh xx.xx.xx.xx 9042

Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH.
You might try "pip install cassandra-driver".

Python: /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Module load path: ['/usr/share/cassandra/lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/usr/share/cassandra/lib/futures-2.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b', '/usr/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Error: can't decompress data; zlib not available

[root@qlg73 bin]#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.